# SQLite query returns an empty cursor

Tags: sqlite

This query returns nothing. I suspect the issue is somewhere in the WHERE line but I cannot figure it out. Any help would be highly appreciated!

```
select companies.name, offers.salary, offers.bonus, offers.equity
from offers
join companies
    on companies.id = offers.company_id
join students
    on students.id = offers.student_id
where students.dob = (select max(dob) from students);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps there is nothing to return - it depends on the data.  Try running this script:

```
#!/bin/sh

sqlite3 <<EOS
create table companies(id integer primary key, name text);
create table students(id integer primary key, dob);
create table offers(salary,
                    bonus,
                    equity,
                    company_id references companies(id),
                    student_id references students(id));

insert into companies(id, name) values(1, 'Company X');
insert into companies(id, name) values(2, 'Company Y');

insert into students(id, dob) values(101, 19910101);
insert into students(id, dob) values(102, 19920202);
insert into students(id, dob) values(103, 19930303);

insert into offers(salary, bonus, equity, company_id, student_id)
            values('\$80K/yr', '\$6000', 'unknown', 1, 101);
insert into offers(salary, bonus, equity, company_id, student_id)
            values('\$70K/yr', '\$5000', 'unknown', 2, 102);
insert into offers(salary, bonus, equity, company_id, student_id)
            values('\$60K/yr', '\$4000', 'unknown', 2, 103);

select 'Companies:';
select * from companies;

select '';
select 'Offers:';
select * from offers;

select '';
select 'Students:';
select id, dob from students;

select '';
select '-----';
select companies.name, offers.salary, offers.bonus, offers.equity, dob
from offers
join companies
    on companies.id = offers.company_id
join students
    on students.id = offers.student_id
where students.dob = (select max(dob) from students);

EOS
```

The final select should return an answer.  Now delete the 3rd insert into the offers table.  The final select will not return anything, as expected.

Comment: I was convinced that there was something to return but I was wrong. Thanks a lot for your help!